# How does Spring's @Scheduled annotation work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-scheduled

In my app I have 3 scheduled methods in 3 separate classes:

```
@Component
public class ClassA {
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000L)
    public void methodA(){
        //do task "A"
    }
}

@Component
public class ClassB {
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000L)
    public void methodB(){
        //do task "B"
    }
}

@Component
public class ClassF {
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000L)
    public void methodF(){
        //do task "F"
    }
}
```

In apps applicationContext there are such lines:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" scheduler="scheduler"/>
<task:executor id="myExecutor"/>
<task:scheduler id="scheduler"/>
```

I can't figure it out from the log files, so here are my questions:

- How do these methods executes? In parallel or successively? If successively then how can it be reconfigured to work in parallel?
- Is this confuguration multithreaded (for each method) or not (and if not - again, how can it be changed)?

Answer (score 4):

It uses the java Executor api in background.
Everything you need to know can be found in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)

You basically choose a TaskExecutor implementation and then set how many processing threads you want.

In your example the 3 methods will be executed continuously with a fixed delay of 5 seconds. But if you define only 1 processing thread, and one method takes a long time, then the execution of the other 2 methods is postponed.
If you don't want to be dependent of the other functions being executed with the @Scheduled, you would need 3 processing threads in this example.